# How to retrieve input value on form submit

Tags: jquery, jsf

I am setting the value to jsf input box using jquery. On event handler I found the value, but on form submit the value is not passing to bean. My jquery code

```
function setValue(){
    $("#inputbox").value("Johny");
}

<h:inputText id="inputbox" value="#{user.name}" onmouseover="$(this).val();"/>
```

How to capture this input value during form submit?

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery code (and your JS `document.getElementById()` code) will **only** work if you turn off the prepending of the element IDs which JSF does in order to prevent duplicate element IDs whenever the components are used more than once in include templates.

You can do this by setting the `prependId` attribute of the parent `<h:form>` to `false`.

```
<h:form prependId="false">
```

---

As to the real problem: jQuery/JavaScript runs on the client side and they works with the HTML DOM tree which JSF has generated in the webserver and the webserver has sent to the webbrowser. Rightclick the page in the webbrowser and choose *View Source*. Do you see it? A form like

```
<h:form id="myform">
    <h:inputText id="myinput" />
```

get generated like follows:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="myform:myinput" name="myform:myinput" />
```

You need to use exactly this client ID in jQuery/JS. Since `:` is an illegal character in CSS selectors, you'd need to select it a bit differently in jQuery:

```
 $("[id='myform:myinput']").val("newvalue");
```

However it works fine as follows in plain JS:

```
 document.getElementById("myform:myinput").value = "newvalue";
```

Answer (score 0):

give name to the input text(name should be exact same as it is in bean)

```
<h:inputText name="{user.name}" value="#{user.name}" onmouseover="$(this).val();"/> 

in bean-the variable name should be-(i am just giving an example) 
private name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working with javascript

```
document.getElementById('inputBox').value = 'Johny';
```

Comment: that's good...your code shoul work either it's jQuery or javascript, but my question is how it's getting mapped to bean without having name attribute in it?